Magento 2 Add a SKU search field outside the filters, next to the keyword search in product Grid
I want to create a SKU filter in the product grid similar to the keyword search. I followed the below approach, and the filter works. However, there's an issue: the filter isn't considered for mass actions, so it applies to all products instead. How can I resolve this, or is there another way to do it?
catalog_product_index.xml
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Test\General\Block\Adminhtml\Skusearch" name="sku_search" before="-" template="Test_General::sku_search.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>

sku_search.phtml
<form id="sku_search_form" method="get">
<label for="sku_search">SKU:</label>
<input type="text" name="sku" id="sku_search" placeholder="Search by SKU" value="<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getSessionValue()) ?>" />
<button type="submit" class="primary"><?= __('Search') ?></button>
<button type="button" id="reset-sku-search"><?= __('Reset') ?></button>

Block - Skusearch.php
namespace Test\General\Block\Adminhtml;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Template;
use Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface;

class Skusearch extends Template
{
    /**
     * @var SessionManagerInterface
     */
    private $session;

    /**
     * Construct function
     *
     * @param Template\Context $context
     * @param SessionManagerInterface $session
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        SessionManagerInterface $session,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    /**
     * Get session value
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getSessionValue()
    {
        $value = '';
        if ($this->session->getData('sku_search')) {
            $value = $this->session->getData('sku_search');
        }
        return $value;
    }
}

di.xml
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider">
    <plugin name="custom_sku_filter_plugin" type="Test\General\Plugin\ProductGridSkuFilter" />
</type>    

ProductGridSkuFilter.php
namespace Test\General\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Filter;

class ProductGridSkuFilter
{
    /**
     * @var RequestInterface
     */
    private $request;

    /**
     * @var SessionManagerInterface
     */
    private $session;

    /**
     * Construct function
     *
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     * @param SessionManagerInterface $session
     */
    public function __construct(RequestInterface $request, SessionManagerInterface $session)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    /**
     * Before Get data function
     *
     * @param ProductDataProvider $subject
     * @return void
     */
    public function beforeGetData(ProductDataProvider $subject)
    {              
        $params = $this->request->getParams();
        $skuSearch = '';
        if ((isset($params['sku'])) && $params['sku']) {
            $skuSearch = $params['sku'];
            $this->session->setData('sku_search', $skuSearch);
        } else {
            $skuSearch = $this->session->getData('sku_search');
        }
        if (!empty($skuSearch)) {
            $subject->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('sku', ['like' =>  $skuSearch ]);
        }
    }   
}


To ensure the filter is respected during mass actions, you need to inject your custom filter into the data provider's search criteria. This affects both the grid and the mass action context.
Modify ProductGridSkuFilter.php
namespace Test\General\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Filter;

class ProductGridSkuFilter
{
    /**
     * @var RequestInterface
     */
    private $request;

    /**
     * @var SessionManagerInterface
     */
    private $session;

    /**
     * Construct function
     *
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     * @param SessionManagerInterface $session
     */
    public function __construct(RequestInterface $request, SessionManagerInterface $session)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    /**
     * Before Get data function
     *
     * @param ProductDataProvider $subject
     * @param array $data
     * @return void
     */
    public function beforeGetSearchResult(ProductDataProvider $subject)
    {
        $params = $this->request->getParams();
        $skuSearch = '';

        if (isset($params['sku']) && $params['sku']) {
            $skuSearch = $params['sku'];
            $this->session->setData('sku_search', $skuSearch);
        } else {
            $skuSearch = $this->session->getData('sku_search');
        }

        if (!empty($skuSearch)) {
            $filter = new Filter();
            $filter->setField('sku');
            $filter->setValue('%' . $skuSearch . '%');
            $filter->setConditionType('like');

            $subject->getSearchCriteria()->addFilter($filter);
        }
    }
}

If mass action filtering is still not consistent, override the getSearchCriteria method in the data provider directly using a plugin
public function beforeGetSearchCriteria(ProductDataProvider $subject)
{
    // Add custom SKU filter logic here.
}


Both of these functions are not loading with this filter.
